# Hierarchical Grouping in MariaDB

Tags: tree, mariadb, aggregate, hierarchical-data, rollup

I am trying to aggregate hierarchical usage from jobs in a compute farm into a format that it can be piped directly into `xdu` to see a treegraph of usage. Conceptually the data can be grouped into a `/project/team/user` hierarchy. For example let's say my job table looks like:

```
jobid    project    team     user         walltime_seconds
1        projA      rd       fred         123
2        projA      rd       lucy         17
3        projA      qa       joe          19
4        projB      qa       frank        100
5        projB      support  amy          7
```

I am looking for output that looks like:

```
159 /projA
140 /projA/rd
123 /projA/rd/fred
17 /projA/rd/lucy
19 /projA/qa
19 /projA/qa/joe
107 /projB
100 /projB/qa
100 /projB/qa/frank
7 /projB/support
7 /projB/support/amy
```

My query:
`select sum(walltime_seconds), concat('/', project, '/', team, '/', user) from job`

of course gives me all the leaf sums but not the sums for the intermediate tree nodes. Is there a good way to get the aggregates for the intermediate nodes as well?

My company uses MariaDB 10.3.8.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? The best answer will depend on whether you are using the latest version of MySQL.

Comment: We're using MariaDB 10.3.8

Answer (score 1):

The may be a better option, but if it's only 3 levels, a simple option is to calculate the totals for each level and union the results together

```
SELECT CONCAT('/', project) AS Node, SUM(Walltime_Seconds) AS Total_Seconds
FROM   YourTable
GROUP BY CONCAT('/', project)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('/', project, '/', team) AS Node, SUM(Walltime_Seconds) AS Total_Seconds
FROM   YourTable
GROUP BY CONCAT('/', project, '/', team)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('/', project, '/', team, '/', user) AS Node, SUM(Walltime_Seconds) AS Total_Seconds
FROM  YourTable
GROUP BY CONCAT('/', project, '/', team, '/', user)
ORDER BY Node
```

**Results:**

| Node | Total_Seconds |
| --- | --- |
| /projA | 159 |
| /projA/qa | 19 |
| /projA/qa/joe | 19 |
| /projA/rd | 140 |
| /projA/rd/fred | 123 |
| /projA/rd/lucy | 17 |
| /projB | 107 |
| /projB/qa | 100 |
| /projB/qa/frank | 100 |
| /projB/support | 7 |
| /projB/support/amy | 7 |

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a good option; I'll be curious to check its performance across my data set (about 75M records), but it probably shouldn't be too much slower than my leaf-node calculation, if at all slower.

That is a much simpler solution than some of the hoops I've been jumping through trying to get this to work!

Comment: Yeah, not ruling out the possibility of better options, but union all was the simplest approach I could find, since the data set isn't a typical hierarchy (i.e. in the parent node+child node sense). But I'd be curious about the performance in comparison to the other methods.